# I have made a Form through cloning. But Cannot add button to the left of input tag. jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am beginner and didn't post the question fully last time so I wasn't answered. I am posting it again please consider it :).

I have created a form dynamically in JQuery. What I want to do is add buttons to the left of the labels in the form (like a column). I have tried `append()`, `insertbefore()`, `prepend()` but they do not provide the results that I require. I have attached an image to give the idea. There are labels of the form shown and then after the labels are their respective inputs. The buttons are to be placed before the labels on the left.

[image]

Thanks :)

```
//The form in html:

<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
  // the jquery to dynamically create input button

var text_input = $('<button/>', {
text: "Text Input",
id: 'btn_',
click: function () {

    var original_form = $('form').last();
    var template = $('form input').first();
    var new_input = template.clone();

    new_input.insertAfter(original_form);
 }
});

 $('form').prepend(text_input).css(??);  // everything works except this last line where I want this button to be on the left of the input of the form, I think here some css has to be added but I don't know what it is
```

Comment: I've embedded image, improved formatting slightly (for easier reading)

Comment: Why not make the original form the way you want it?

Comment: I didn't understand?